# How to publish the same value to differently named topics with different delays for each

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I’m looking for a way to publish the same value (number taken from an html input) to several  differently named topics.

For each topic that value must be delayed, so I’m using the window.setTimeout()

There are the same numbers of different topics than different delay, which are found are in the Array tabDel[] (one delay for one topic)

So, for example I want to publish the number 421 to topic ESP0/ledstate at delay 0 then the same 421 to topic ESP1/ledstate at delay 500ms then 421 to ESP2/ledstate at delay 1000ms

Of course if I had only 3 topics to publish to with 3 different delay it would be simple, but I could have 100 topics for that project.

The problem is I’m not able to get the value both delayed and published on the different topics : I can't get the value published on the right topic with the corresponding delay (all is driven by the for loop)

So, as said for this I’m using a "for" loop.

The issue seems to come from client.send(message) because everything else takes the for loop in account with no problem.

```
var xTopic = 3; // 100 …


function joueursCascade(){

     for (var i = 0; i <= xTopic; i++) //
     {  
          doSetTimeout(i);
     }
}


function doSetTimeout(i)
{

    // - m  : payload from html input
       message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(document.getElementById('btn3').value);

    // -t : several topics from several html input (input id=esp1, id=esp2…)
    // .value is the topic : ESP0/ledstate, ESP1/ledstate etc..
    message.destinationName = document.getElementById('esp'+i).value;

    //delays Array
    var del = tabDel[i];

    //PUBLISH message ISSUE : I tryed
    //1)this publish same message on all topics but with no delays, ok
    mon_client.send(message);

    //2) this publish message for the higher topic in the loop at successive delays
    window.setTimeout(function(){sendMess(message);}, del);

    //3) same than 2)
    window.setTimeout(function(){mon_client.send(message);}, del)

    //monitor
    console.log('esp'+i);
    console.log("doSetTimeout "+document.getElementById('btn3').value);
    console.log("message.destinationName: " + message.destinationName);
    console.log(del);
}


function sendMess(message)
{
    mon_client.send(message);
}
```

Here’s the html:

```html
    <div><p>cascades</p>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" value="0" id="btn3">
        <button onclick="joueursCascade()">start</button>
        </div>

    <div><p>ESP-XXXXXX</p>
    <input type="text" name="client" id="esp0" value="ESP0/ledstate"><br>
    <input type="text" name="client" id="esp1" value="ESP1/ledstate"><br>
    <input type="text" name="client" id="esp2" value="ESP2/ledstate"><br>
```

Comment: Would you consider using some back-end process that's a bit more sophisticated (Java?) to handle the delayed publishing, that's connected to the same MQTT broker and is listening to the single message pushed out by your HTML input / JS component?  Like, your input generates a single message that your delayed publisher subscribes to, and then it can use TimerTask or ScheduledExecutor or whatever to "replay" the message on an incrementing set of topics.  This also decouples the delayed publishing logic from your HTML front-end.

Comment: Thank you ! it really helps. Now the code works with your advices. However what option do I have in JS to auto-replay the function with (as you said) something like a TimeTasker or ScheduledExecutor? Is there some special lib or function for that?

Comment: You'd have to use something like Node.js if you wanted a server-side JS component.  I don't know Node that well, but should be pretty straightforward... use setInterval() to publish at fixed intervals once you receive the initial message from the front end.

Comment: Ah yes, NodeJS ans setInterval(), I've seen them. Ok :)